# VS 2015 linker error, precompiled headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse cdt with the visual studio 2015 toolchain. After a lot of tinkering with all the different options and such i have got it almost working with precompiled headers now. In a prebuild step i create the precompiled header from stdafx.cpp and use it in other files. Compiling works well, but when it comes to linking i get the following error: `Logger.obj : error LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in; image may not run`

Logger.obj is created from Logger.cpp which is one of my own files and gets compiled in the process. I figured its probably because the entire Logger class is a template and there is no real code in Logger.cpp, but even trying to use stuff thats included from stdafx.h does not change this.

Does anyone maybe know what the error actually means? I saw some postings when having several libraries, but in my case its actually one of my own files, not from a library. I would appreciate any hint!

Comment: Are you including stdafx.obj in the list of files to link?  Looking up the error number on msdn tells you that you need to link with it.

Comment: Eclipse with Visual Studio? Once you turn IntelliSense off Visual Studio is a pretty good IDE on it's own. It's debugger is certainly better than anything Eclipse can do.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Hah, thats it!

Comment: @john If the IDE would work I would use it. But after wiping everything several times and multiple session with microsoft support I lost my patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include stdafx.obj in the list of files to link (from my comment).

Comment: How do I include the stdafx.obj in the list of files to link?

Comment: @TheShmoo if you are using Visual Studio then add the path to your .obj file in Linker-> Input-> Additional Dependencies

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment! Hopefully it will help someone else!